# Rowcolors in a longtable with three parts

Tags: longtable, booktabs, colortbl, rowcolor, threeparttablex

I have a `longtable` inside a `ThreePartTable` environment and I want to have alternating row colors across page breaks. I want to have no color on the first row, since the header is also colored. The problem is that when the `longtable` breaks the first row is different. I've tried to work with `\hidecolors` and `\showcolors` in different places.

[image: First header]

[image: Second header]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm,top=35mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
    \newcommand{\ltnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{gray!25}
\newcommand{\topline}{\arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}}
\newcommand{\midline}{\arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[a] elektrische Bruttoleistung
        \item[b] elektrische Nettoleistung 
    \end{TableNotes}
    \rowcolors{7}{gray!10}{white}
    \small
    \begin{longtable}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l
        S[table-format=2.2]
        S[table-format=3.2]>{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}
        S[table-format=5.0]@{}} \hiderowcolors
        \caption{Zusammenstellung der GuD-Kraftwerke in Deutschland, Energieerträge aus dem Jahr 2019} \\ \showrowcolors
        \topline
        Kraftwerk & {Energie in \si{TWh}} & {Anteil in \si{\percent}} & {Leistung in \si{\MW}\ltnote{a}} \\
        \midline
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{4}{c}{{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- Fortsetzung}} \\
        \topline
        Kraftwerk & {Energie in \si{TWh}} & {Anteil in \si{\percent}} & {Leistung in \si{\MW}\ltnote{a}} \\
        \midline    
        \endhead

        \bottomrule \hiderowcolors
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot \showrowcolors

        Berlin Lichterfelde  & 0,52 & 1,55  & 432 \\
        Berlin Mitte GuD     & 1,92 & 5,71  & 440 \\
        Bremen Mittelsbüren  & 1,3  & 3,87  & 238 \\
        Burghausen           & 0,13 & 0,39  & 178 \\
        Dormagen GuD         & 0,85 & 2,53  & 561\tnote{b}\\
        Dresden GT           & 1,41 & 4,2   & 260 \\
        Düsseldorf A         & 0,27 & 0,8   & 103 \\
        Düsseldorf E         & 0    & 0     & 420 \\
        Düsseldorf F         & 2,91 & 8,66  & 595 \\
        Duisburg 3B          & 1    & 2,98  & 245 \\
        Emsland B            & 0,9  & 2,68  & 475 \\
        Emsland C            & 0,19 & 0,57  & 475 \\
        Emsland D            & 3,82 & 11,37 & 887 \\
        Gersteinwerk F       & 0,02 & 0,06  & 427 \\
        Gersteinwerk G       & 0,12 & 0,36  & 427 \\
        Gersteinwerk I       & 0    & 0     & 427 \\
        Gersteinwerk K1      & 0,02 & 0,06  & 112 \\
        Hamburg Tiefstack    & 0,29 & 0,86  & 321 \\
        Hamm 10              & 0,87 & 2,59  & 425 \\
        Hamm 20              & 0,88 & 2,62  & 425 \\
        Hannover Linden      & 0    & 0     & 255 \\
        Herdecke H6          & 0,99 & 2,95  & 400 \\
        Irsching 4           & 0    & 0     & 569 \\
        Irsching 5           & 0,03 & 0,09  & 860 \\
        Karlsruhe RDK 4      & 0    & 0     & 365 \\
        Knapsack 1           & 2,51 & 7,47  & 800 \\
        Knapsack 2           & 1,49 & 4,43  & 430 \\
        Köln Merkenich       & 0    & 0     & 220 \\
        Köln Niehl           & 4,31 & 12,82 & 324 \\
        Kiel Küstenkraftwerk & 0,05 & 0,15  & 190 \\
        Leipzig Nord GuD     & 0,42 & 1,25  & 172 \\
        Ludwigshafen         & 4,88 & 13,53 & 1019 \\
        München GT2          & 0,13 & 0,39  & 139 \\
        München GT61         & 0,55 & 1,64  & 125 \\
        München GT62         & 0,53 & 1,58  & 124 \\
        Saarbrücken          & 0,29 & 0,86  & 123 \\
        \midrule
        Summe                & 33,6 & 100   & 14420 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The rowcolors strictly follow the alternating pattern here. If the last row on the previous page is white, the first row on the following page will be colored. You can use `\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!10}` to start the table with a white background "Berlin Lichterfelde ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm,top=35mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
    \newcommand{\ltnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{gray!25}
\newcommand{\topline}{\arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}}
\newcommand{\midline}{\arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[a] elektrische Bruttoleistung
        \item[b] elektrische Nettoleistung 
    \end{TableNotes}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!10}
    \small
    \begin{longtable}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l
        S[table-format=2.2]
        S[table-format=3.2]>{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}
        S[table-format=5.0]@{}} \hiderowcolors
        \caption{Zusammenstellung der GuD-Kraftwerke in Deutschland, Energieerträge aus dem Jahr 2019} \\ \showrowcolors
        \topline
        Kraftwerk & {Energie in \si{TWh}} & {Anteil in \si{\percent}} & {Leistung in \si{\MW}\ltnote{a}} \\
        \midline
        \endfirsthead
        \hiderowcolors
\caption{Fortsetzung}\\
%        \multicolumn{4}{c}{{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- Fortsetzung}} \\
        \topline
        Kraftwerk & {Energie in \si{TWh}} & {Anteil in \si{\percent}} & {Leistung in \si{\MW}\ltnote{a}} \\
        \midline    
        \endhead

        \bottomrule \hiderowcolors
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot \showrowcolors

        Berlin Lichterfelde  & 0,52 & 1,55  & 432 \\*
        Berlin Mitte GuD     & 1,92 & 5,71  & 440 \\
        Bremen Mittelsbüren  & 1,3  & 3,87  & 238 \\*
        Burghausen           & 0,13 & 0,39  & 178 \\
        Dormagen GuD         & 0,85 & 2,53  & 561\tnote{b}\\*
        Dresden GT           & 1,41 & 4,2   & 260 \\
        Düsseldorf A         & 0,27 & 0,8   & 103 \\*
        Düsseldorf E         & 0    & 0     & 420 \\
        Düsseldorf F         & 2,91 & 8,66  & 595 \\*
        Duisburg 3B          & 1    & 2,98  & 245 \\
        Emsland B            & 0,9  & 2,68  & 475 \\*
        Emsland C            & 0,19 & 0,57  & 475 \\
        Emsland D            & 3,82 & 11,37 & 887 \\*
        Gersteinwerk F       & 0,02 & 0,06  & 427 \\
        Gersteinwerk G       & 0,12 & 0,36  & 427 \\*
        Gersteinwerk I       & 0    & 0     & 427 \\
        Gersteinwerk K1      & 0,02 & 0,06  & 112 \\*
        Hamburg Tiefstack    & 0,29 & 0,86  & 321 \\
        Hamm 10              & 0,87 & 2,59  & 425 \\*
        Hamm 20              & 0,88 & 2,62  & 425 \\
        Hannover Linden      & 0    & 0     & 255 \\*
        Herdecke H6          & 0,99 & 2,95  & 400 \\
        Irsching 4           & 0    & 0     & 569 \\*
        Irsching 5           & 0,03 & 0,09  & 860 \\
        Karlsruhe RDK 4      & 0    & 0     & 365 \\*
        Knapsack 1           & 2,51 & 7,47  & 800 \\
        Knapsack 2           & 1,49 & 4,43  & 430 \\*
        Köln Merkenich       & 0    & 0     & 220 \\
        Köln Niehl           & 4,31 & 12,82 & 324 \\*
        Kiel Küstenkraftwerk & 0,05 & 0,15  & 190 \\
        Leipzig Nord GuD     & 0,42 & 1,25  & 172 \\*
        Ludwigshafen         & 4,88 & 13,53 & 1019 \\
        München GT2          & 0,13 & 0,39  & 139 \\*
        München GT61         & 0,55 & 1,64  & 125 \\
        München GT62         & 0,53 & 1,58  & 124 \\*
        Saarbrücken          & 0,29 & 0,86  & 123 \\
        \midrule
        Summe                & 33,6 & 100   & 14420 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the * do?

Comment: The `*` prevents a pagebreak after this specific row. In your example, you had the pagebreak after "Karlsruhe RDK 4", in my example, the page breaks occurs right before "Karlsruhe RDK 4".

Comment: I would be grateful if you could give a help with my relevant question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/601446/2288.