# Understanding how \rowcolors work with longtables

Tags: tables, longtable, colortbl

For the following, I would like to understand:

1. What is the first row considered by `colortbl`? The header or that one with numbers `1 & 2`?
2. Why doesn't the coloring respect `\rowcolors{3}` and skip the first row below the header? I expected it to start coloring the row `3 & 4` while having colorless header and first row.
3. Why does the header in the second page get colored?
4. How to make the coloring pattern consistent in both table parts after considering my first two questions?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight = 45mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \rowcolors{3}{gray!15}{}
    \begin{xltabular}{0.5\linewidth}{X X}
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        One & Two \\
        \midrule\endfirsthead
        \midrule
        One cont. & Two cont. \\
        \midrule\endhead
        \midrule\endfoot
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]\endlastfoot
        1   & 2     \\
        3   & 4     \\
        5   & 6     \\
        7   & 8     \\
        9   & 10    \\
        11  & 12    \\
        13  & 14    \\
        15  & 16    \\
        17  & 18    \\
        19  & 20    \\
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the head and foot rows are counted in the position they are in the source and as they are boxed they wil appear in the same colour each time they are used ignoring the parity of the row count at that point. you can use `\rowcolor` to force the first and following heads to have the same color.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would be grateful if you could give me a complete code considering my questions to fully understand what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, to make a decent long table with header and footer, it is better to separate table head/foot (which includes caption, footnote, continued text) and row head/foot (which includes some rows of the table that should appear in every page). In this way, row colors should work as expected.

The [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package recently added support for long tables based on the above idea. Version 2021L of `tabularray` was released on 2021-07-01.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=75mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\begin{tblr}[
  long, caption = {The Caption},
]{
  width = 0.5\linewidth, colspec = {XX}, rowhead = 1,
  row{even} = {gray!30}, row{1} = {blue!15},
}
\toprule[1.5pt]
  One & Two  \\
\midrule
   1  &   2  \\
   3  &   4  \\
   5  &   6  \\
   7  &   8  \\
   9  &  10  \\
  11  &  12  \\
  13  &  14  \\
  15  &  16  \\
  17  &  18  \\
  19  &  20  \\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tblr}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

> (1) Is there a way to separately change the width of \toprule and \midrule of the running header in addition to the rules of footers?

I am not sure what you mean.

> (2) Also, how to change the (Continued) text?

Use `\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{...}` and `\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{...}`.

> (3) How to specify the row at which the coloring pattern should start?

First `row{even} = {gray}` then `row{2,4}={white}` to overwrite the former.

> (4) Finally, what does rowhead mean since it is not in the documentation?

Option `rowhead` means the number of rows at the beginning of the table which should be typeset on every page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. **(1)** Is there a way to separately change the width of `\toprule` and `\midrule` of the running header in addition to the rules of footers? **(2)** Also, how to change the `(Continued)` text? **(3)** How to specify the row at which the coloring pattern should start? **(4)** Finally, what does `rowhead` mean since it is not in the documentation?

Comment: @Diaa I have updated the answer for your comment. Also you need to wait for the stable release for the complete documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. My first comment means that is it possible to make the thickness of toprule, for example, in the first page different from that of the following pages?

Comment: @Diaa No, a decent long table should have consistent appearance on every page.

Comment: @Diaa In the above example, the bottom rules have different widths. It's a bug to be fixed.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give that degree of freedom to make the user customize the width of every rule regardless the nominal consistent looking. Thanks for developing this helpful package.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could take a look at my relevant question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604122/2288. Thanks!

Comment: How can I totally eliminate the element `contfoot`? Since `\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}` removes the text but keeps its assigned vertical space below the table which I don't need. I need to do the same for `conthead` and the whole caption.

Comment: @Diaa Maybe you can ask a new question which shows what you want with longtable or xltabular package, just as your last question. Comment is not enough for this.